# ionic - iFrames not showing on ios when live

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, iframe, content-security-policy

So this one has me completely stumped.

We have an app that is built on Ionic framework (CLI version 4.1.1)

The app accepts credit card numbers from the user via a hosted field through a company we use (Splash Payments). This just means they insert iFrames onto the screen for the credit card number, expiration date and CVV number fields.

When we test it locally on our computer by serving it all works fine. When we build the app and test it through xCode, all works fine, however when we actually release it to the app store (we are pushing the code update via Code Push), the fields just never appear.

At first we realized it was probably the Content Security Policy so we played around with that for awhile and came up with this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https://s3.amazonaws.com https://api.OURCOMPANY.com https://codepush.azurewebsites.net 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src https://codepush.azurewebsites.net https://api.splashpayments.com https://api.OURCOMPANY.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src https://api.splashpayments.com https://code.jquery.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src https://api.splashpayments.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src https://api.splashpayments.com 'self'; media-src *" />
```

After that not working, we tried adding

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

to the config.xml file.

Neither of these worked. We still get no fields on the payments form.

Any idea why these iFrames arent showing?

Here's an image of the form populating by running it through xCode directly onto the phone:
[image]

Here's a picture of it not working when live 
[image: NOT working when live]

Comment: I just realized, I don't believe Code Push updates the config.xml (I believe that requires an app store update through apple). I am going to try and submit a build to Apple with the new lines in config.xml and will update if that works.

Comment: hi, can I know this worked or not? I'm facing the same issue here

Comment: @kavindhi Code Push updates everything in the www folder (which does not include config.xml) so I believe config.xml is NOT updated by Code Push. My issue was resolved by correcting the Content Security Policy & updating it through the apple app store.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solved the issue by adding adding 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src * 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
      style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' gap:;
      script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' gap:; frame-src *;">

to my index.html

Comment: @kavindhi no problem, however I do want to point out that * means "wildcard" aka any source... that opens you up to vulnerabilities because if there was a security flaw in your app someone could add full iframes, edit the css, add javascript code etc. Instead you should only add the base URL of the iFrame. Example if you were using Splash Payments like us, they include a CSS file, a javascript AND an iFrame so I put

Comment: @kavindhi
  script-src 'self' https://api.splashpayments.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
  style-src 'self' https://api.splashpayments.com 'unsafe-inline'; 
  frame-src 'self' https://api.splashpayments.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';

Comment: @kavindhi by making it 'self' and specific URLs, you're saying ONLY these sources can do these things. So if hackernet.hackers.com tried to embed their code externally, it would be blocked. Wish you the best of luck!